# How to bind Object's property to an UIlabel using RXSwift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a Model class like below:

```
class Model{
    var currentTemparature:String?
    var minTemparature:String?
    var maxTemparature:String?

    init(currentTemparature:String,minTemparature:String,maxTemparature:String) {
        self.currentTemparature = currentTemparature
        self.maxTemparature = maxTemparature
        self.minTemparature = minTemparature
    }
}
```

I want to bind each of these properties to an UILabel in the ViewController using RXSwift.

For Example:

```
class ViewController:UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet var currentTemparatureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var minTemparatureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var maxTemparatureLabel: UILabel!

    func UpdateLabels(){
        let model = Model.init(currentTemparature: "25", minTemparature: "20", maxTemparature: "30")
        currentTemparatureLabel.text = model.currentTemparature
        minTemparatureLabel.text = model.minTemparature
        maxTemparatureLabel.text = model.maxTemparature
    }
}
```

When ever the value of the model's properties changes, i want to update the label. How can i achieve that?

Comment: What did you already research/tried?

Comment: I tried binding a single string variable to a label using BehaviorRelay.

Comment: What would cause the values to change?

Answer (score 0):

You should have an Observable of your data Model (that might be fetch from a server for example) and then, you can directly bind the result of it to your label using the .bind(yourlabel.rx.text)

Every time the value will change it will also update your view with the binding to your label

Answer (score 0):

Try using BehaviorRelay

Don't forget to import *RxSwift*, *RxCocoa*

```
class Model{
    var currentTemparature: BehaviorRelay<String?>
    var minTemparature: BehaviorRelay<String?>
    var maxTemparature: BehaviorRelay<String?>

    init(currentTemparature:String,minTemparature:String,maxTemparature:String) {
        self.currentTemparature = .init(value: currentTemparature)
        self.maxTemparature = .init(value: maxTemparature)
        self.minTemparature = .init(value: minTemparature)
    }
}
```

```
class ViewController:UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet var currentTemparatureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var minTemparatureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var maxTemparatureLabel: UILabel!

    private var bag = DisposeBag()

    func UpdateLabels(){
        let model = Model.init(currentTemparature: "25", minTemparature: "20", maxTemparature: "30")
        
        model.currentTemparature.bind(to: currentTemparatureLabel.rx.text).disposed(by: bag)
        model.minTemparature.bind(to: minTemparatureLabel.rx.text).disposed(by: bag)
        model.maxTemparature.bind(to: maxTemparatureLabel.rx.text).disposed(by: bag)

    }
}
```